# How to Upload a text file in django using templateview based view and model based forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and stuck on uploading a simple file. I am using TemplateView as views and model based form. I am stuck here. I have no idea what to do. I am using django 2.0. I have attached the code what I have done so far.

**setting.py**

```
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    SECRET_KEY = 'key_hash'
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'Aamir.apps.AamirConfig',
    ]
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'first.urls'
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
            ,
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first.wsgi.application'
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'NAME': 'dbname',
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'USER': 'arshad',
            'PASSWORD': 'arshad',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
                'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            }
        }
    }
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_TZ = True
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py (project)**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include
    import Aamir.views as views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('Aamir.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    ]
```

**urls.py (app)**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    import Aamir.views as views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
        path('index/', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
        path('summerizer/', views.SummerizerView.as_view(), name='summerizer'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from .forms import FileUploadForm
    #from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
    class HomePageView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'Aamir/index.html'

    class SummerizerView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'Aamir/summrizer.html'
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            context = self.get_context_data()
            if context["form"].is_valid():
                print('yes done')
                context["form"].save(commit=True);
                # save your model
                # redirect
            return super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context)

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(SummerizerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            form = FileUploadForm(self.request.FILES)
            context["form"] = form
            return context
```

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    class FileUpload(models.Model):
        upload_file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import FileUpload
    class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = FileUpload
            fields = ('upload_file',)
            widgets = {
                'upload_file': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'accept': 'text/plan', 'id':'fupload',
                                                      'name':'fupload', 'placeholder': 'Brows Files'
                                                      }, ),
            }
            error_messages = {
                'upload_file': {
                    'required': "No filed selected!",
                },
            }

        def save(self, commit=True):
            instance = super(FileUpload, self).save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                # save
                instance.save(update_fields=['name'])
            return instance
```

**apps.py**

```
    from django.apps import AppConfig
    class AamirConfig(AppConfig):
        name = 'Aamir'
```

**summrizer.html**

```
    {% extends "Aamir/include/base.html"%}
    {% block page_title %}Summerizer{% endblock %}
     {% block content %}
         <style>
         legend {
            display: block;
            -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
            -webkit-padding-end: 2px;
            border-width: initial;
            width: initial;
            font-size: initial;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            border-style: none;
            border-color: initial;
            border-image: initial;
        }
         fieldset {
        display: block;
        -webkit-margin-start: 2px;
        -webkit-margin-end: 2px;
        -webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
        -webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
        -webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
        -webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
        min-width: -webkit-min-content;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: lightgrey;
        border-image: initial;
    }
         </style>
         {% load staticfiles%}
            <div class="section-container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                      <h1 class="text-center">Summerizer</h1>
                   </div>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend style="color:lightgrey;font-weight:bold;">Upload File</legend>
                            <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
                                {% endif %}
                                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <!--label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Upload File:</label-->
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <!--input type="file" accept="text/plain" class="form-control" id="fupload" placeholder="Brows for file" name="fupload"-->
                                            {{ form.upload_file }}
                                            {% for field in form %}
                                                <span style="color:#b92c28">{{ field.errors }}</span>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btnupload" name="submit">
                                                Upload
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Upload File:</label>
                                        {{ form }}
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <br>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend style="color:lightgrey;font-weight:bold;">Summery</legend>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0px">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background: lightgrey;border:1px solid lightgrey">
                                            <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;margin:0.5em;">Summery</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:10px">
                                            <div class="text-area-result" style="max-height:400px;min-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;padding: 0;width: 100%">
                                                <p id="result-text">

                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 0px">
                                    <br class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background: lightgrey;border:1px solid lightgrey">
                                            <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;margin:0.5em;">File Content</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:10px">
                                            <div class="text-area-result" style="max-height:400px;min-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="section-container">
                <div class="container text-center">
                  <div class="row section-container-spacer">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">

                      <h3>Do you like it ?</h3>
                      <p>
                        <a href="https://facebook.com/" class="social-round-icon fa-icon" title="">
                          <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="social-round-icon fa-icon" title="">
                          <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="social-round-icon fa-icon" title="">
                          <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
     {% endblock %}
```

**Project Directory Structure**
[image]

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with this code. But why are you using TemplateView rather than a more appropriate view that knows about forms, such as CreateView?

Comment: Dear sir Thanks for your comment. I am unable to upload file. And I am new so don't know which works best.

Comment: Can you login to my system via teamviewer?